# Need Help Sorting Two Columns in One Select Statement

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I know that I can sort one column of data using `ORDER BY`, but I want to sort two columns with `ORDER BY` and have the results appear in one table view.

I tried using comma separated list, but that doesn't sort the way I want it to. I want it to sort both columns independent of the rows having to be at particular positions.

```
SELECT * FROM top_5_films ORDER BY position DESC;
```

I want both columns of data to be sorted and not have the fields being tied to the rows.

Comment: This is unclear. Would you please show sample data and expected results?

Comment: This would create rows of unrelated data, right?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by @forpas, you seem to be looking to create records of unrelated data; this is quite a odd requirement in SQL...

Assuming that your RDBMS supports window function `ROW_NUMBER()`, you could proceed as follows:

- for each of the two columns, create a subquery that selects the column and assigns a row number to each record, sorted by the column itself
- then `JOIN` both subqueries on their row number
- finally, sort by row number

Consider:

```
SELECT c1.col1, c2.col2
FROM 
    (
        SELECT col1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY col1) rn FROM top_5_films
    ) c1
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT col2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY col2) rn FROM top_5_films
    ) c2  ON c1.rn = c2.rn
ORDER BY c1.rn
```

---

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/Y7kNo75xjPqJXGHwXUn5L/0)**:

Sample data:

```
| col1 | col2 |
| ---- | ---- |
| ghi  | RST  |
| abc  | UVW  |
| lmn  | OPQ  |
```

Results:

```
| col1 | col2 |
| ---- | ---- |
| abc  | OPQ  |
| ghi  | RST  |
| lmn  | UVW  |
```

Comment: What does the c1 in c1.col1 mean? Also what does rn mean? I'm using MariaDB. Also I ran the code in the fiddle you made and I got a syntax error.

Comment: @CoolBuys; `c1` is the alias for the first subquery. `(
        SELECT col1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY col1) rn FROM top_5_films
    ) c1`

Comment: I ran this and I got a syntax error: create table top_5_films (col1 varchar(5), col2 varchar(5));

insert into top_5_films values('ghi', 'RST');
insert into top_5_films values('abc', 'UVW');
insert into top_5_films values('lmn', 'OPQ');

SELECT * FROM top_5_films;


SELECT c1.col1, c2.col2
FROM 
    (
     SELECT col1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY col1) rn FROM top_5_films
 ) c1
 INNER JOIN (
     SELECT col2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY col2) rn FROM top_5_films
 ) c2  ON c1.rn = c2.rn
ORDER BY c1.rn

Comment: Also what does rn stand for?

Comment: I don't know how to make the whole query. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: @CoolBuys: which RDMBS and version are you using? Like : MySQL 8.0, Oracle 11g, ...?

Comment: 10.1.37-MariaDB

Comment: I added a semicolon to the end of the query and I still get a syntax error with no tables being displayed.

Comment: The first query SELECT * FROM top_5_films; runs but the query below it results in an error and I can't see the table sorted.

Comment: @CoolBuys: in MariaDB, window functions (such as ROW_NUMBER()) are available starting version 10.2. So sadly this solution will not work for your RDBMS version...

Comment: There's no other solution?

Comment: There's a solution on this site but I can't figure it out. Please help. http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/

Comment: I updated my mariadb to 10.2.10. Your code works. Thanks.